# c# datetime string format

Tags: c#, string, datetime

Can't seem to get this one right. What format string should I use for the following `DateTime` input ?

```
2013-08-24T19:29:26.4050000
```

I want to extract the date.

I tried:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(localTime, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff", null).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

But this doesn't work for me, plus I feel there must be a way to avoid the multiple "f" at the end (I just need the date, don't care about the hour)

Thanks, Li

Comment: Doesn't DateTime.TryParse do the stuff for you, it should read this format easily I guess. Or you can simply Split date from T and still get what you need.

Comment: "this doesn't work for me" doesn't say anything about what happens. Please be more specific.

Comment: This looks like you're not storing times as UTC. If you store times as UTC you can convert them consistently and easily to any timezone without worrying about the input format.

Comment: This article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536633/net-parsing-iso-8601-string-to-datetime seems to be the one you're looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't gave us any information about your error and since we don't know your culture, here and it works with [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx);

```
string localTime = "2013-08-24T19:29:26.4050000";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(localTime, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Output will be;

```
8/24/2013 7:29:26 PM
2013-08-24
```

Here a <kbd>[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/kBzUMq)</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the format of `XMLDateTime` use `XmlCovert` for this purpose.

```
string fmt = "2013-08-24T19:29:26.4050000";
var dt = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(fmt, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Unspecified);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/N9k0Ot)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are parsing an ISO 8601 datetime string.  This article [Parsing ISO 8601 string to DateTime in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536633/net-parsing-iso-8601-string-to-datetime) seems to be the one you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the below solution to get the result in dd/MMM/yyyy format in string variable:

```
string _dateTime=string.Empty;

_dateTime=localTime.ToString(dd/MMM/yyyy);
```

So for the date 2013-08-24T19:29:26.4050000 will return you as 24/Aug/2013